# Shading or bevels are not aligned

Tags: modifiers, shaders, edit-mode, vertices, bevel

I am not sure if this is a bevel or shading issue, but I have been trying to move arround the vertices to fix it but it seems not to be working.  Disolving the edges doesn't seem to work to. Any idea how to go about this?

[image]

Comment: Where is the problem? Can you highlight in the image?

Comment: P.s. it seems your mesh is not done with quads (planes with 4 vertexes) and this can bring your mesh to have visualization's problems.

Comment: My apologies  the issue was the dark shading and bevel issue as highlighted in this image. https://ibb.co/1LPNZZz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by rearanging the vertices from the top view, which made the shape aligned again.  [image]

Comment: As @Sanbaldo said in his comment, a hint in your question what exactly is wrong would have been helpful - it's not easy to see in the screenshot that those vertices are in a place where they shouldn't be without knowing what the geometry is supposed to look like.

Comment: My apologies the issue was the dark shading and bevel issue as highlighted in this image. ibb.co/1LPNZZz